# Converting an mp4 file to wav or mp3 file in R

Tags: r, wav, mp4, converters

I am working on speech to text in R and I have successfully converted an mp3 file to wav but i need to convert mp4 to wav or mp3 in R.

thank very much for your answers.

Burak

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html and download FFmpeg for your OS.

Then, from within R you should be able to use

```
system("ffmpeg -i PATH/TO/FILE.mp3 PATH/TO/FILE.mp4")
```

Comment: tahnk you for your answer, i downloadd ffmpeg and i added into path "C:\ffmpeg" but when i run the command nothing happens

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20495/how-do-i-set-up-and-use-ffmpeg-in-windows

Comment: I followed the tutorial well but when I run the code in R no action and yet no error message

Comment: I am not sure how to help you. You might have a problem with the specific path. I assume you are on Windows? On my Mac it works without problems.

Comment: yes i am on windows 10, i used several function like system, system2 and shell

Comment: but shell funcition return the execution of "ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -f mp3 music.mp3" failed with error code 1

Comment: Did you try to use the **full path** to both files instead?

Comment: yes, i tried but it's the same things